# Fundamental representation bases and generalized minors

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, geometric-representation-theory, flag-varieties, cluster-algebras

Let $G$ be a simple simpy connected complex algebraic group.

I was wondering if there is a clear relationship between the generalized minors (defined by Berenstein, Fomin and Zelevinsky) and bases of the coordinate ring of a flag variety or at least its fundamental representations.

Is there such a relationship?

Comment: The generalized minors of Berenstein, Fomin, Zelevinsky correspond to the extremal weight vectors in the fundamental representations.